# How to count and get text from li using selenium

Tags: selenium

The below is my DOM

```
<div class="demo-frame">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
#feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height:  56px; }

</style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
$( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
} );
</script>
    <ol id="selectable" class="ui-selectable">
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 7</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I need to click on each of the Items and print the Item Names in a sequential order, In order to do so I am trying to get the count of the li tags and then iterate using a for loop

```
List<WebElement> countryUL = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='demo-frame']/ol"));

System.out.println(countryUL.size());
```

But the above prints "1" I do not know the mistake I am making

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
List<WebElement> countryUL = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='demo-frame']/ol/li"));
```

Your xPath is not getting into the `ol`. In order to count `li` items you should fix your path like I've shown so that it would take leaf nodes you need.

You also need to consider that clicking an item might make your DOM get rebuilt so that the elements in your list would go stale. If this will be the case, the better solution would be going item by item using approach like `//your_xpath[number_of_element]`.

Test that works fine:

```java
public void testListIteration() {
    driver.get("https://demoqa.com/selectable/");
    List<WebElement> countryUL = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='demo-frame']/ol/li"));
    for(WebElement item: countryUL){
        item.click();
        boolean isSelected = item.getAttribute("class").contains("ui-selected");
        if(!isSelected){
            System.out.println("Test FAILED");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me out in detail please ? This is the [UI](https://demoqa.com/selectable/) I'm trying to automate, I need to click on each item and get the text of it

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> olElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("ol"));
// other options if above does not work
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='selectable']"));
// driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-selectable"));
// driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ol#selectable"));

List<WebElement> liElements = olElements.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
System.out.println("liElements" + liElements.size());
        for(int i=0;i<liElements.size();i++)
            liElements.get(i).getText();
```

Comment: @AmitJain : `driver.findElement(By.tagName("ol"));` returns `webelement` not `list`.

Comment: @KunduK - updated, some how missed.. written loop as he is asking to print also all them items..